# getops still performs default actions when arguments are provided

Tags: bash, shell

I've recently started working with the getopts command in bash. I am confused as to why my script runs the dafult action "cat ~bin/Temp/log.txt | ~bin/Scripts/report.pl" when arguments have been provided. I only want that to run if no arguments were passed to the shell script. I've used getopts:Std in perl where I was able to code somthing like:

```
unless ($opts{d}) {
do something...}
```

How would I code something like that in a shell script? Also, how would I code logic such as this:

```
if ($opts{c}) {
    cat ~bin/Temp/mag.txt | ~bin/Scripts/report.pl -c
}
elsif ($opts{d} {
    cat ~bin/Temp/mag.txt | ~bin/Scripts/report.pl -d
```

My code:

```
#!/bin/sh
while getopts cd name
do
        case $name in
          c)copt=1;;
          d)dopt=1;;
             *)echo "Invalid arg";;
        esac
done

if [[ ! -z $copt ]] #Specifies what happens if the -c argument was provided
then
   echo "CSV file created!"
    cat "~/bin/Temp/log.txt" | ~/bin/Scripts/vpnreport/report.pl -c
fi
if [[ ! -z $dopt ]] #Specifies what happens if the -d argument was provided
then
   echo "Debug report and files created"
    cat ~bin/Temp/mag.txt | ~bin/Scripts/report.pl -d
fi

if [[ ! -z $name ]]     #Specifies what happens if no argument was provided 
then
    echo "Running standard VPN report"
    cat ~bin/Temp/log.txt | ~bin/Scripts/report.pl
fi 

shift $(($OPTIND -1))
```

My Output:

```
[~/bin/Scripts/report]$ sh getoptstest.sh
Running standard report
[~/bin/Scripts/report]$ sh getoptstest.sh -d
Debug report and files created
Running standard report
[~/bin/Scripts/report]$
```

The two getopts commands are vasty different from bash to perl and I just can't seem to get the hang of the bash varient even after reading several tutorials. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Whether or not anything is passed `name` is going to be set by the call to `getopts`. It always sets it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took Jeff's answer and rewrote my script so it works now:

```
#!/bin/bash
while getopts cd name
do
    case $name in
      c)carg=1;;
      d)darg=1;;
         *)echo "Invalid arg";;
    esac
done
#Specifies what happens if the -c argument was provided:
if [[ ! -z $carg ]]
    then
    if [[ -z $darg ]]
        then
            echo "CSV created"
            cat ~bin/Temp/log.txt | ~bin/Scripts/report.pl -c
else 
    echo "Debug CSV created"
    cat ~bin/Temp/log.txt | ~bin/Scripts/report.pl -cd
    fi
fi
#Specifies what happens if the -d argurment was provided:
if  [[ ! -z $darg ]]
    then
    echo "Debug report created"
    cat ~bin/Temp/log.txt | ~bin/Scripts/report.pl -d
#Specifies what happens if no  argument was provided:
else
    echo "Standard report created"
    cat ~bin/Temp/logs.txt | ~bin/Scripts/report.pl
fi
```

Thank you again for your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

On the final run of `getopts`, your variable (`name`) will be set to "?".

```
#!/bin/bash
while getopts abc foo; do :; done
echo "<$foo>"
```

Output of the above:

```
$ ./mytest.sh 
<?>
$ ./mytest.sh -a
<?>
```

Insead, use `elif`, which is like Perl's `elsif`:

```
if [[ ! -z $copt ]]
then
  # ...
elif [[ ! -z $dopt ]]
then
  # ...
else
  # ...
fi
```

Or test `if [[ -z $copt && -z $dopt ]]`, or so forth. Other notes:

- See the official `if` and `case` documentation [in the Bash manual under "Conditional Constructs"](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs).
- `[[ ! -z $name ]]` means the same as the more-direct `[[ -n $name ]]`.
- Use `#!/bin/bash` instead of `#!/bin/sh`, or switch off of `[[` in favor of `[`. The double square bracket (and your use thereof) is specific to bash, and [rarely works with sh](https://serverfault.com/a/52050).